# How do the incremental games work when the user is offline?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to write an incremental game like Swarm simulator, or Adventure capitalist. How do these games solve the problem when the user is offline the things are keep going?

I mean it is easy to increment a value in local storage every x second, but when the user close the window it has to send its stats to the backend which has to continue this task to increase the values.

Is the backend just generates it out when the user comes online? If yes, then how?

Comment: maybe it doesn't do that much. It only saves the time when you turn off and compare with the time you turn on. Then do some fancy calculation :D

Comment: If you are using `localStorage`, you can try sending data to server and on fail, set/update a single fail-safe key. On page load, check for this key and again send it to server and continue.